# Too many readings

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning Firebase, can you somehow get over the 50K reading limit? I don't want to release a product with Firebase, but I'm learning it and that's why I got 50K readings by accident. Do you have any way? Creating a new project is not an option because I can only create 2.

Comment: We can't tell you where the reads came from since we can't observe your app. But they usually come from the console.

Comment: I do not want to know where I have these readings from, I want to be able to continue learning the firestore without such a problem that I have to pay for it. Is there a test mode where you can read more than 50k and you don't have to pay anything?

Comment: You can use [Firebase Emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) to run your code locally. That does not incur any charges and should be good for learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documented limits for the free tier](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#free-quota) cannot be exceeded.  They are hard limits.

You can use the [emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore) locally on your machine if you want to experiment without cost.